# Probability density function of a ratio with summation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_i$ be a random variable that is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$ for all $i\in\{1,\dotsc, n\}$ for some $n$.

Let $Y_i$ for all $i$ be the random variable defined by:

$$Y=\dfrac{X_i}{\displaystyle\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}X_j},$$

How can I calculate the pdf of $Y_i$?

N.B. all the random variable $X_i$ are i.i.d.

My try:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 F_{Y_i}(y) = \mathbb{P}(Y_i \leqslant y) &= \mathbb{P}(X_i \leqslant z \sum_{j\neq i}X_j)\\& = \mathbb{E}_{\sum_{j\neq i}X_j}\left( \mathbb{P}(X_i \leqslant z \sum_{j\neq i}X_j | \sum_{j\neq i}X_j)\right) \\&= \mathbb{E}_{\sum_{j\neq i}X_j}\left( F_{X_i}(z \sum_{j\neq i}X_j)\right) \\&= 1 - \mathbb{E}_{\sum_{j\neq i}X_j}\left(e^{-\lambda y \sum_{j\neq i}X_j}\right)
\end{split}
\end{align}
$$

If I am correct, I cannot continue.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $Z_{i}=\sum_{j\ne i}X_i$ and $k=n-1$ ($Z_i\sim \text{Gamma}(k,\lambda)$). Then for $y\ge 0$

$$P\{Y_i\le y\}=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[1\{X_i\le yZ_i\}|Z_i]]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[1-e^{-\lambda yZ_i}]=1-\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda yz}\times \frac{\lambda^k z^{k-1}e^{-\lambda z}}{(k-1)!}dz$$
$$=1-\frac{(1+y)^{-k}}{\Gamma(k)}\int_0^\infty x^{k-1}e^xdx=1-(1+y)^{-k}$$

and

$$f_{Y_i}(y)=k(1+y)^{-(k+1)}$$